# Kivy [Freezes on button press]

Tags: python, kivy

so i'm trying to learn simple Kivy GUI to send SMS with a class i already made earlier, it works except the window freezes for a couple seconds, any tips on how to make the button press smooth and not freeze at all? Keep in mind the code below is just the beginning of the application, just to make sure it actually works. Thanks in advance.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.config import Config

from sms_funksjon import SendSMS


Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')  # 0 being off 1 being on as in true/false
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '500')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '200')


class MyGrid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Mobil nummer: "), pow(50, 50))
        self.mobile_number = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.mobile_number)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Tekst: "))
        self.tekst = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.tekst)
        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.pb = ProgressBar(max=100)
        self.pb.value = 0
        self.add_widget(self.pb)

        self.submit = Button(text="Send", font_size=40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        nummer = str(self.mobile_number.text)
        tekst = str(self.tekst.text)
        SendSMS(nummer, tekst)
        self.clear_everything()

    def clear_everything(self):
        self.mobile_number.text = ""
        self.tekst.text = ""


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


Main().run()
```

Comment: How long does it take to execute the SendSMS function?

Comment: You're executing the function that takes a while in the main thread of your application. Your main thread therefore cannot do anything else and freezes up. You'll need to try to run your send sms function in a separate thread using the `threading` module. Or if your send sms function is a call to a REST API, you can use the `UrlRequest` which is threaded by default.

Comment: @Erik sounds like the start of an excellent answer!

Comment: Need to know more about the SendSMS function before being able to put a decent answer!